# SourceTree is not refreshing the file changes and stage unstage status - windows

Tags: windows, git, bitbucket, atlassian-sourcetree

Recently SourceTree stopped working and do not refresh the files which are changed. It was working fine for a year. My settings are correct. "**Refresh  automatically when files change**" is also checked in options -> general.

When I change or stage a file I have to close and then reopen the Source Tree to see the changes.

I was also not able to resolve the conflicts as external tool was not opening.

Answer (score 1):

I did several attempts bt restarting the computer and uninstalling reinstalling the software. But it was still behaving same. Because it was not deleting the directory `C:\Users\[your-username]\AppData\Local\Atlassian\SourceTree` on uninstall.

Following solution helped me fix the issue.

1. Close **SourceTree**
2. Go to the **directory** `C:\Users\[your-username]\AppData\Local\Atlassian`
3. Rename **SourceTree** to **_SourceTree** (in order to backup your configurations)
4. Open **SourceTree** and it was working.

Comment: I'm using an older version of SourceTree (1.7.0.32509) that occasionally has this issue where it stops updating, and **this does fix it**. _Pro tip:_ Replace `bookmarks.xml` and `opentabs.xml` in your new `Atlassian\SourceTree` directory (_after_ you've followed these instructions, I suppose) and it's like you never left.